# Ease action to simulate a clank in a moving or rotating device near end of the trajectory

Tags: animation

You know those mechanisms that moved or rotated, and then just a few millimeters near the end of the trajectory they oppose a bit of resistance and then clank to the final position.

I want to simulate that clank with an ease function that can be combined with the [standard ease actions](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html). The link is for reference to some examples of ease transition functions, but I just need the pseudocode like this:

```
float clankActionTime(float t) {
    if (t > 0.9)
        return (0.5*sin(10.0*t*2.0*M_PI)+2.0*10.0*t)/20.0;
    return t;
}
```

That is what I have so far, which gives this graph for t between 0 and 1.

[image]

But I want something more like this:

[image]

Where A and B are parameters passed to the ease function to indicate where to star the clank and how deep is the valley near the end of the curve, respectively.

Comment: You linked to the documentation for a specific library and tech (actionscript); is the use of those a requirement for your solution?

Comment: @SethBattin No, just a function `t = myfunc(t)` in pseudo code that have a graph like the one in the second image

Comment: Can't it be just piecewise linear? Or you want some smoothing?

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou I think the curve can be constructed from strait lines, because the smoothness would be hardly noticeable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
clankTime(t, A, B) {
    float cT = 1.0-A;
    float t1 = cT+0.5*(1.0-B)*(1.0-cT);
    float t2 = cT+0.5*(1.0+B)*(1.0-cT);

    if (t > t1) {
        float m = (1.0-t2)/(1.0-t1);
        return m*(t-t1)+t2;
    }
    else if (t > cT) {
        float m = (t2-cT)/(t1-cT);
        return m*(t-cT)+cT;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Where **A** is the duration of the clank from where the movement starts slowing down until the end of the ease transition, and **B** is how deep is the valley measured on a line perpendicular to `y=x` that intersects the line at `0.5*A`.

[image]